# Creating a link to a rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2.3
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
get '/books/:author', to: 'books#index'
get '/books/:author/show', to: 'books#show'
post '/books/:author/create', to: 'books#create'
```

Which, when running rake: routes, gives me:

```
GET    /books/:author(.:format)  books#index
GET    /books/:author/show(.:format)  books#show
POST   /books/:author(.:format)  books#create
```

When a route helper is not provided by rake: routes, can I assume that when I create a link to it in a view, I can use use the model name, like: books_path or books_url? something like:

```
= link_to books_path(:author => @author), :method => :post
```

I tried it, but I am getting an error message:

```
undefined method books_path
```

So, I am either doing something wrong in routes.rb, or I am not referencing it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an unnamed route.  I think what you want in your particular situation is:

```
  resources :books, only: [:index, :show, :create], param: :author
```

That will give:

```
                   Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                    books GET  /books(.:format)                                                                         books#index
                          POST /books(.:format)                                                                         books#create
                     book GET  /books/:author(.:format)                                                                 books#show
```

This does not seem RESTful to me though.  I think what you really want is a nested resource between books and authors.  Check out the Rails guides on routing for more information: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: This works, but I will look at nested resources to see if I can modify my approach

Answer (score 2):

Just to pile on, I suggest you use nested routes:

```
resources :authors do 
  resources :books, shallow: true 
end
resources :books, only: [:index, :create, :new]
```

Which will give you (amongst other things):

```
   author_books GET    /authors/:author_id/books(.:format)      books#index
                POST   /authors/:author_id/books(.:format)      books#create
new_author_book GET    /authors/:author_id/books/new(.:format)  books#new
      edit_book GET    /books/:id/edit(.:format)                books#edit
           book GET    /books/:id(.:format)                     books#show
                PATCH  /books/:id(.:format)                     books#update
                PUT    /books/:id(.:format)                     books#update
                DELETE /books/:id(.:format)                     books#destroy
        authors GET    /authors(.:format)                       authors#index
                POST   /authors(.:format)                       authors#create
     new_author GET    /authors/new(.:format)                   authors#new
    edit_author GET    /authors/:id/edit(.:format)              authors#edit
         author GET    /authors/:id(.:format)                   authors#show
                PATCH  /authors/:id(.:format)                   authors#update
                PUT    /authors/:id(.:format)                   authors#update
                DELETE /authors/:id(.:format)                   authors#destroy
          books GET    /books(.:format)                         books#index
                POST   /books(.:format)                         books#create
       new_book GET    /books/new(.:format)                     books#new
```

That ought to give you everything you need to manage authors and books.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get how `post '/books/:author/create', to: 'books#create'` gives you `POST   /books/:author(.:format)  books#create`.

If you want to name your custom routes add the name with the `:as` option: `get 'something', to: 'controller#action', as: 'something'` to get "something_path" as a valid helper.

Note that you are going away from RESTful routes, if you want rails to do the things it usually do (like the named routes helpers) you should stick with it's conventions: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html